# .vimrc script for compiling with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, vim, g++

I want to write a short script in my .vimrc to compile .cpp files with g++ in vim and open the errors/output in a new vertical buffer to my actual file like this:

1. create a vim command "**:set vimcompiling**" that induces the following steps
2. save the file: "**:w**"
3. compile it: "**:make ./name**" (without leaving vim!)
4. open the file in a new buffer:
   *if there are errors:* "**:vert copen n**"
   *else:* execute the file in a **new vertical buffer**
5. map these steps (2-4) to "**F5**" so I can execute step 2-4 any time I want to compile

Can anyone give me some tips on how to write such a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BuildToolsWrappers](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) already has this built in and bound to F5.

Executing `:make %<` is easy. However detecting errors to open the quickfix window or not is more tricky. In BTW I use the following

```
" Function: lh#btw#build#_show_error([cop|cwin])      {{{3
function! lh#btw#build#_show_error(...) abort
  let qf_position = lh#option#get('BTW_qf_position', '', 'g')

  if a:0 == 1 && a:1 =~ '^\%(cw\%[window]\|copen\)$'
    let open_qf = a:1
  else
    let open_qf = 'cwindow'
  endif

  " --- The following code is borrowed from LaTeXSuite
  " close the quickfix window before trying to open it again, otherwise
  " whether or not we end up in the quickfix window after the :cwindow
  " command is not fixed.
  let winnum = winnr()
  cclose
  " cd . is used to avoid absolutepaths in the quickfix window
  cd .
  exe qf_position . ' ' . open_qf

  setlocal nowrap

  " if we moved to a different window, then it means we had some errors.
  if winnum != winnr()
    " resize the window to just fit in with the number of lines.
    let nl = 15 > &winfixheight ? 15 : &winfixheight
    let nl = lh#option#get('BTW_QF_size', nl, 'g')
    let nl = line('$') < nl ? line('$') : nl
    exe nl.' wincmd _'

    " Apply syntax hooks
    let syn = lh#option#get('BTW_qf_syntax', '', 'gb')
    if strlen(syn)
      silent exe 'runtime compiler/BTW/syntax/'.syn.'.vim'
    endif
    call lh#btw#filters#_apply_quick_fix_hooks('syntax')
  endif
  if lh#option#get('BTW_GotoError', 1, 'g') == 1
  else
    exe origwinnum . 'wincmd w'
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at BTW